# How to get an element from list of list

Tags: c#, list, console, int, division

I wrote program and I used in that program a list of lists (in int type).
Every list in the big list stores a different number of integers but when I try to approach those integers and use them for division I don't know how.

That's the program:

```
        Console.WriteLine("How many students in the class?");
        int students = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<List<int>> studentsclass = new List<List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many jumps student number " + (i + 1) + " did?");

            int studentjumps = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Write student number " + (i+1) + " high jumps: ");

            List<int> jumps= new List<int> (studentjumps);

            for (int j = 0; j < studentjumps; j++)
            {
                jumps.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < studentsclass.Count; k++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < studentsclass[m].Count; m++)
            {
```

(That is a program that calculates student's average high jumps).
The rest of the code should be:  sum = sum\index M of index K of the list.

Edit:

I continued my code and then when it came to the division part I've got lots of errors.
this is what I wrote:

```
for (int k = 0; k < studentsclass.Count; k++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m < studentsclass[m].Count; m++)
            {
                sum = sum + studentsclass[k][m];
            }
            sum = (double)sum \ studentsclass[m]; \\<-- Error
            Console.WriteLine("student number " + (k + 1) + " did an average of " + sum + " meter high jumps");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use.

```
studentsclass[k][m]
```

to access the inner list

and use

```
studentsclass[k].Count
```

in your second for loop

Comment: or I guess your fourth for loop. technically

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can do somthing like the following to get your desired result:

```
var result = studentsclass.Select((l, i) => new { Id = i, Average = l.Average() });
```

See [THIS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xVR3XG) fiddle.